# Close popup then it open after 30 mintues

Tags: jquery, html, css, cookies, popup

This is **html**, **css** and **js**. I want to when popup open and close the popup then it open after **30 minutes**. I don't know why I am not setting this popup or missing something. Please guide me.
I have download popup script from 
 http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/jQuery-Plugin-To-Show-A-Popup-Only-Once-Per-Visitor-First-Visit-Popup.html

**jquery.firstVisitPopup.js**

```
(function ($) {

    'use strict';

    $.fn.firstVisitPopup = function (settings) {

        var $body = $('body');
        var $dialog = $(this);
        var $blackout;
        var setCookie = function (name, value) {
            var date = new Date(),
                expires = 'expires=';
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (60*30000);
            expires += date.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; ' + expires + '; path=/';


        }

        var getCookie = function (name) {
            var allCookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
                cookieCounter = 0,
                currentCookie = '';
            for (cookieCounter = 0; cookieCounter < allCookies.length; cookieCounter++) {
                currentCookie = allCookies[cookieCounter];
                while (currentCookie.charAt(0) === ' ') {
                    currentCookie = currentCookie.substring(1, currentCookie.length);
                }
                if (currentCookie.indexOf(name + '=') === 0) {
                    return currentCookie.substring(name.length + 1, currentCookie.length);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        var showMessage = function () {
            $blackout.show();
            $dialog.show();

        }

        var hideMessage = function () {
            $blackout.hide();
            $dialog.hide();
            setCookie('fvpp' + settings.cookieName, 'true');
            $('#fvpp-close').click(function() {
            $('#my-welcome-message').hide();
            $limit = 9999;
        });     

        }

        $body.append('<div id="fvpp-blackout"></div>');
        $dialog.append('<a id="fvpp-close">&#10006;</a>');
        $blackout = $('#fvpp-blackout');

setTimeout(function(){


        if (getCookie('homepage' + settings.cookieName)) {
            hideMessage();


        } else {

            showMessage();

        }
 },5000);


        $body.on('click', '#fvpp-close', hideMessage);


    };

})(jQuery);
```

**css**

```
<style>
    body { margin-top: 0; }

#container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #EEE;
}

h1,
p { padding: 1em 1em; }

#fvpp-blackout {
  display: none;
  z-index: 499;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#my-welcome-message {
  display: none;
  z-index: 500;
  position: fixed;
  width: 36%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 20%;
  padding: 20px 2%;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #FFF;
}

#fvpp-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#fvpp-dialog h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}

#fvpp-dialog p { margin: 0; }
</style>
```

**Html**

```
<div id="container">
          <h1>jQuery First Visit Popup Demo</h1>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur elementum quam sed sapien adipiscing quis vehicula ante placerat. Nulla id magna nisl, ac luctus metus. Nunc sagittis, libero interdum volutpat porttitor, enim ligula fringilla tortor, vel scelerisque dolor orci ac erat. Aliquam et urna risus. Vivamus justo justo, sagittis ac egestas pellentesque, lobortis at dui. Phasellus faucibus commodo ante id eleifend. Sed ullamcorper suscipit malesuada. Phasellus feugiat diam eget ligula tempus suscipit eu at tortor. Fusce egestas aliquam quam nec bibendum. Ut lobortis, urna non lobortis pellentesque, ipsum nisl fermentum augue, eu iaculis felis sem eget erat. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce vel quam nunc. Fusce neque massa, venenatis non porttitor non, viverra eget lorem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed at lobortis nisi. Pellentesque sagittis eros malesuada nisi commodo eu tincidunt eros lobortis.</p>


        </div>
<div id="my-welcome-message">
          <h2>Welcome to my site</h2>
          <p>Hello, welcome to my website.</p>
        </div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.firstVisitPopup.js"></script> 
<script>
            $(function () {
                $('#my-welcome-message').firstVisitPopup({
                    cookieName : 'homepage'
            });

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Are you expecting a person to sit on one page for 30 minutes, or do you want this to be a site-wide counter?

Comment: hello @RoryMcCrossan ! I am expecting when a person visit then popup will come (onload) when person close the popup then its show again after 30 minutes without refreshing the page.

Comment: So if they DO refresh the page, the 30 min counter would reset?

Comment: Hello @timo !!!  Yes ! if  a person do refresh then 30 minutes counter  would reset.